# i have installed scrapy, but get error when i execute "scrapy startproject tutorial"

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have the following output, what is the reason?

```
    bater:test001 apple$ scrapy startproject tutorial
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 4, in 
        import pkg_resources
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in 
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Scrapy==0.16.1
```

Comment: i have fixed it, i must reopen an new terminal after the installation of distribution, thanks for review my question.

Comment: shouldn't the question be closed then?